# email logo is the same for self emails

Tags: email-templates, magento2.3.3

I am using magento 2.3.3.
I configured the new logo. When I create a new customer account the email sent to the customer contains the new logo, but the email copy sent to me has always the luma logo.
I tried to delete all the luma images in the directories but still got the luma logo.
The header.html contains `src="{{var logo_url}}"`. I don't know where to set the right logo for email sent to myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are an issue in magento 2.3.3 transnational email logo upload. You can fixed this issue by this below process. The you can upload the logo from there and you problem will be solved. I am also faced the same issue but now it is solved.

First you have to go to this below page by

**Admin login => Content => Design => Confgiuration => Click on edit your Main Website => then scroll and you get this below section.**

This image upload field is wrong. This is file upload field not image and also not working.

[image]

You have to create this above field like this below image upload field
[image]

**Now the below code is to convert the field:**

Create /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1" schema_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Email"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Then overwrite the page:**

**From :**
/vendor/magento/module-email/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

**To:**
/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

And change code with this below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="other_settings">
        <fieldset name="email">
            <settings>
                <level>1</level>
                <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                <label translate="true">Transactional Emails</label>
            </settings>
            <field name="email_logo" formElement="imageUploader">
                <settings>
                    <notice translate="true">To optimize logo for high-resolution displays, upload an image that is 3x normal size and then specify 1x dimensions in the width/height fields below.</notice>
                    <label translate="true">Logo Image</label>
                    <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <imageUploader>
                        <settings>
                            <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                            <maxFileSize>2097152</maxFileSize>
                            <uploaderConfig>
                                <param xsi:type="string" name="url">theme/design_config_fileUploader/save</param>
                            </uploaderConfig>
                        </settings>
                    </imageUploader>
                </formElements>
            </field>
            <field name="email_logo_alt" formElement="input">
                <settings>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="validate-no-html-tags" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Logo Image Alt</label>
                    <dataScope>email_logo_alt</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </field>
            <field name="email_logo_width" formElement="input">
                <settings>
                    <notice translate="true">Necessary only if an image has been uploaded above. Enter number of pixels, without appending "px".</notice>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="validate-digits" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <dataType>number</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Logo Width</label>
                    <dataScope>email_logo_width</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </field>
            <field name="email_logo_height" formElement="input">
                <settings>
                    <notice translate="true">Necessary only if an image has been uploaded above. Enter image height size in pixels without appending "px".</notice>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="validate-digits" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <dataType>number</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Logo Height</label>
                    <dataScope>email_logo_height</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </field>
            <field name="email_header_template" formElement="select">
                <settings>
                    <notice translate="true">Email template chosen based on theme fallback, when the "Default" option is selected.</notice>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Header Template</label>
                    <dataScope>email_header_template</dataScope>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <select>
                        <settings>
                            <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template\Header"/>
                        </settings>
                    </select>
                </formElements>
            </field>
            <field name="email_footer_template" formElement="select">
                <settings>
                    <notice translate="true">Email template chosen based on theme fallback, when the "Default" option is selected.</notice>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Footer Template</label>
                    <dataScope>email_footer_template</dataScope>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <select>
                        <settings>
                            <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template\Footer"/>
                        </settings>
                    </select>
                </formElements>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then run

**bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**bin/magento cache:flush**

**Give permission to the pub, generated, var folder**

And then upload your logo from there and send email to check email logo.